# Set style of html element by targeting it's id in Blazor

Tags: javascript, html, css, blazor, styling

Say I have an element in Blazor. I want to set the elements style based on the value of the input field in Blazor. I am aware that you can do this by using if else blocks in the html code however I want to avoid this as it grows the code base extremely quick. A function would be better which evaluates the incoming object and styles it.

for instance if I have the element below which passes a value the value is passed to a function.

`<th><InputText placeholder="First Name" id=FirstName @bind-Value="@filterModel.FirstName">First Name</InputText></th>`

Function

```
    private async void UpdateVisibleData(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e){
        Console.WriteLine(e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName + " Change Detected");
        var fieldChanged = e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName;
        var IsEmptyString = FindEmptyStringInField(filterModel, fieldChanged);
        if(IsEmptyString){
            element.style.setProperty('--my-variable-name', 'hotpink');
           }
        }
```

I havent been able to get the style.setproperty part to work. not sure what other methods there are. Open to JSInterop. preferrable though if I can target the style.setproperty function and get this working.

Answer (score 3):

### Revised Answer

Or you can use JSInterop like this:

/wwwroot/js/example.js

```
export function examplefunction (Id, Color) {
    document.getElementById(Id).style.backgroundColor = Color;
}
```

razor page :

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? module;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/js/example.js");
        }
    }
    private async void UpdateVisibleData(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e){
        var fieldChanged = e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("examplefunction", fieldChanged, "hotpink");
    }
}
```

### Original Answer

I would use ? operator to make simple HTML without additional code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id=FirstName @bind=@textInput style='@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textInput) ? "background-color: hotpink;" : "")' />
```

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference. that increases the codebase across various elements. where declaring a function and sending an element to it reduces it. if it is a once off sure but not for several.

Comment: As I know there is no way to directly access and change style of elements in Blazor. I think you have to use JSinterop then, I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a exact answer by targeting the id. however I did find a workaround for this which isn't too bad for webassembly by passing a conditional function to the style tag on the element. It doesn't grow the code base as much as using if else blocks and declaring individual strings. although still targeting element id based on fieldeventchanges would be less computationally taxing as the conditional function is checked for every statechange on every field which uses it as opposed to only being called on the element id if the condition is met.

html

```
<th><InputText style="@StyleForEmptyString(filterModel.FirstName)" placeholder="First Name" id=FirstName @bind-Value="@filterModel.FirstName">First Name</InputText></th>
```

@code{

````
private string StyleForEmptyString(string fieldValue)
    {
        if (fieldValue == ""){
            return "outline:none; box-shadow:none;";
        }
        return "";
    }```
````